# How can I invoke a WCF operation without HTTP container?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I have an environment in which I cannot add another HTTP container (whether ServiceHost, IIS, etc.) but I still need to process SOAP requests (represented as strings) with a WCF web service.  I was hoping to write a simple wrapper method (C#) such as:

```
string processSoapMessage(string req);
```

In that method, I would manually create a System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message instance with an XML reader that operates on the input string.  I was hoping to avoid writing manual dispatching code by creating a ChannelDispatcher that would process the resulting Message instance, but it seems that ChannelDispatchers are tied to a particular ServiceHost, something I cannot have in my environment if it requires an open port.  Is there some dispatching code I can call to accomplish this without creating a hosting container?

Comment: Where is the SOAP request that you are to process coming from?

Comment: I'm going with Shiraz on this one: if you don't already have an open port, where is the soap from, exactly?

Comment: The web service you have to talk to is on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is happening on the same machine, then using a [Named Pipe](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/05/19/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-1.aspx) binding is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot create a simple console app that will create and open a ServiceHost to host your service class?

Marc

Comment: Anything that requires an open port is prohibited, but it just occurred to me that I might be able to use named pipes endpoints.  I am going to try that.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you do, don't use the `System.String` type to hold XML. Pass an `XmlReader` or `XmlDocument` or something. Always use XML APIs to manipulate XML.